# Can I port forward safely?

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding

Hopefully my question makes sense, is there a way to port forward my router (xfinity) to make it more secure? Like so my data cannot be accessed, and only certain devices (that I choose) can even be accessed. So like I have say 2 computers, one I use and 1 that is a linux server. Is there a way to port forward my router so that it can only access the linux server? Or is this a default thing/not possible? (The ports forwarded on my router will also be firewall setup on my linux server)

Comment: If security is the main focus here, i would reccoment a VPN but this may depend on your use case,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, Port Forwarding and Firewalling are different. as such its perfectly possible to forward a port, and also use firewall rules on the router governing the use of that port (by whom, ratelimiting, etc). Of course your ability to configure this may be limited by the routers user interface, but most will allow you to configure firewall and NAT rules separately.

Second, a DNAT rule (a port forwarding rule) will always identify a single IP in your LAN to forward traffic to for that port. so yes, you can forward a port to just your server. in fact what you can't do is forward the same port on both your systems at the same time.

third, you should only be forwarding one port or a small group of them per service you want to expose to the outside world. you are not trying to open your entire network, just a single service on your server.

You will have to allow traffic on your linux server firewall, and have a process running on it that is listening on that port, which is bound to the LAN IP or 0.0.0.0. you will have to research the configuration for your service if it doesn't listen for remote connections automatically.